# Tastypie how to stop meta query

Tags: django, tastypie

when I create a tastypie API and run a GET on it, it executes a meta query that counts the number of entries on the table.

```
DEBUG [django.db.backends:89] (0.001) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "lookup_job_types"; args=()

DEBUG [django.db.backends:89] (0.000) SELECT "lookup_job_types"."id", "lookup_job_types"."job_type", "lookup_job_types"."category" FROM "lookup_job_types" LIMIT 1000; args=()
```

How expensive is the first query on large tables and how do I disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Make Your own `Paginator` class with

```
class MyPaginator(Paginator):
    def page(self):
        ...
        count = self.get_count(limit=limit, offset=offset)
        ...

    def get_count(self, limit=None, offset=None):
        if limit in (0, self.max_limit) and offset == 0:
            return len(list(self.objects))
        else:
            return super(MyPaginator, self).get_count()
```

This works when `limit = 0` and `offset = 0`. In other cases Tastypie must count all elements to make next and prev links and `meta.total_count`.

This code is from [tastypie-extras](https://github.com/tomi77/django-tastypie-extras) package.